HuggingFace Trainer receive IterableDataset as the input, how to resume from checkpoint and How epoch iter when this kind of dataset occures
Firstly, the trainig args is set by code downbelow. Cause receive IterableDataset,and I pass max_steps as the control button, so the setting goes this way below.
elif args.max_steps > 0:  # Rely on max_steps when dataloader does not have a working size
            max_steps = args.max_steps
            # Setting a very large number of epochs so we go as many times as necessary over the iterator.
            num_train_epochs = sys.maxsize
            num_update_steps_per_epoch = max_steps
            num_examples = total_train_batch_size * args.max_steps
            num_train_samples = args.max_steps * total_train_batch_size
            if args.include_tokens_per_second:
                num_train_tokens = self.num_tokens(train_dataloader, args.max_steps) * args.gradient_accumulation_steps

We can see the resume from checkpoint logic downbelow，cause I use max_steps to control the training ,resulting self.state.global_step % (num_update_steps_per_epoch) always 0，for global_step never surpass max_steps. How can I resume from checkpoint when I use IterabelDataset?
if resume_from_checkpoint is not None and os.path.isfile(
            os.path.join(resume_from_checkpoint, TRAINER_STATE_NAME)
        ):
            self.state = TrainerState.load_from_json(os.path.join(resume_from_checkpoint, TRAINER_STATE_NAME))
            self.compare_trainer_and_checkpoint_args(self.args, self.state)
            self._load_callback_state()
            # num_update_steps_per_epoch = max_steps 
            epochs_trained = int(self.state.global_step // num_update_steps_per_epoch)
            if not args.ignore_data_skip:
                steps_trained_in_current_epoch = self.state.global_step % (num_update_steps_per_epoch)
                steps_trained_in_current_epoch *= args.gradient_accumulation_steps
            else:
                steps_trained_in_current_epoch = 0

Another question:
for epoch in range(epochs_trained, num_train_epochs):
    epoch_dataloader = train_dataloader
    epoch_iterator = iter(epoch_dataloader)

    total_updates = steps_in_epoch // args.gradient_accumulation_steps + 1
    for _ in range(total_updates): # total_updates = max_steps + 1
           update_step += 1
           num_batches = args.gradient_accumulation_steps if update_step != (total_updates - 1) else remainder
           batch_samples, num_items_in_batch = self.get_batch_samples(epoch_iterator, num_batches)
           for i, inputs in enumerate(batch_samples):
               step += 1
    if step < 0:
          logger.warning(
          "There seems not to be a single sample in your epoch_iterator, stopping training at step"
          f" {self.state.global_step}! This is expected if you're using an IterableDataset and set"
          f" num_steps ({max_steps}) higher than the number of available samples."
          )
          self.control.should_training_stop = True

We can see if the batch nums of DataLoader less than max_steps, then it will occures max_steps < 0, the training will stop consequently, rather iter next epoch.
Is my comprehension wrong? Please teach me how! Appreciate!
